# Resample different behaviour with agg and calling the function

Tags: pandas

I have a `pandas.DataFrame` called `data` with this structure:

```
                       id         action
date                                    
1900-11-01 00:00:00  10.0    starts_game
1900-11-01 00:05:00  10.0  team_a_scores
1900-11-01 00:25:00  10.0  team_a_scores
1900-11-01 00:30:00  10.0  team_a_scores
1900-11-01 00:55:00  10.0  team_b_scores
1900-11-01 23:58:00  99.0    starts_game
1900-11-02 00:40:00  99.0  team_b_scores
1900-11-02 00:50:00  99.0  team_b_scores
1900-11-03 00:05:00  10.0    starts_game
1900-11-03 00:24:00  10.0  team_b_scores
```

I want to resample it minute by minute, and take different upsampling strategies. With `id` column I will fill forward it and with `action` I will only fill the upsampled values with 'playing'.

The problem is that the result is different when I make directly a ffill to the resampled datafrrame and with agg function, let´s look at it:

```
data.resample('T').ffill().head()

                       id       action
date                                  
1900-11-01 00:00:00  10.0  starts_game
1900-11-01 00:01:00  10.0  starts_game
1900-11-01 00:02:00  10.0  starts_game
1900-11-01 00:03:00  10.0  starts_game
1900-11-01 00:04:00  10.0  starts_game
```

But remenber, I wanted `action` column to be only the string 'playing', so:

```
data.resample('T').agg(dict(id='ffill', action=lambda _: 'playing')).head()



                       id   action
date                              
1900-11-01 00:00:00  10.0  playing
1900-11-01 00:01:00   NaN  playing
1900-11-01 00:02:00   NaN  playing
1900-11-01 00:03:00   NaN  playing
1900-11-01 00:04:00   NaN  playing
```

I don´t understand why the id doesn´t upsample correctly, any idea?

For easy reproducibility this is the csv:

```
date,id,action
1900-11-01 00:00:00,10.0,starts_game
1900-11-01 00:05:00,10.0,team_a_scores
1900-11-01 00:25:00,10.0,team_a_scores
1900-11-01 00:30:00,10.0,team_a_scores
1900-11-01 00:55:00,10.0,team_b_scores
1900-11-01 23:58:00,99.0,starts_game
1900-11-02 00:40:00,99.0,team_b_scores
1900-11-02 00:50:00,99.0,team_b_scores
1900-11-03 00:05:00,10.0,starts_game
1900-11-03 00:24:00,10.0,team_b_scores
```

And the code:

```
import pandas as pd


filename = 'your_custom_name.csv'
data = pd.read_csv(filename)

data = data.set_index('date')
```

Comment: I just get it but not in a very pretty way... and doesn´t answer my question, but it works:

data = (data[['id']]
        .resample('T')
        .ffill()
        .join(data[['action']],
               how='left')
        .fillna('sleeping'))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why `agg` isn't working is that `resample('T')` returns a `groupby`-like structure with groups being the minute-by-minute rows

```
>>> data.resample('T').groups
{Timestamp('1900-11-01 00:00:00', freq='T'): 1,
 Timestamp('1900-11-01 00:01:00', freq='T'): 1,
 Timestamp('1900-11-01 00:02:00', freq='T'): 1,
 Timestamp('1900-11-01 00:03:00', freq='T'): 1,
 Timestamp('1900-11-01 00:04:00', freq='T'): 1, ...
```

`agg` is applied over a group which in this case is just a single row meaning that the lambda would happily return a scalar and `ffill` would take the only element available to it.

Had you resampled it by e.g. a day

```
>>> data.resample('D').groups
{Timestamp('1900-11-01 00:00:00', freq='D'): 6,
 Timestamp('1900-11-02 00:00:00', freq='D'): 8,
 Timestamp('1900-11-03 00:00:00', freq='D'): 10}
```

it would have been the other way around. Your lambda would return just a single value for the entire 6 elements of the first group but the `'ffill'` method would work as expected propagating the first encountered non-`NaN` value forward

```
>>> data.resample('D').agg({'id': 'ffill', 'action': lambda _: 'playing'})
                       id   action
date                              
1900-11-01 00:00:00  10.0  playing
1900-11-01 00:05:00  10.0      NaN
1900-11-01 00:25:00  10.0      NaN
1900-11-01 00:30:00  10.0      NaN
1900-11-01 00:55:00  10.0      NaN
1900-11-01 23:58:00  99.0      NaN
1900-11-02 00:00:00   NaN  playing
1900-11-02 00:40:00  99.0      NaN
1900-11-02 00:50:00  99.0      NaN
1900-11-03 00:00:00   NaN  playing
1900-11-03 00:05:00  10.0      NaN
1900-11-03 00:24:00  10.0      NaN
```

I'm not sure if the entire operation can be done in one go but the following should work

```
df = data.resample('T').first()
df['id'] = df['id'].ffill()
df['action'] = df['action'].fillna('playing')
```

giving you

```
                       id         action
date                                    
1900-11-01 00:00:00  10.0    starts_game
1900-11-01 00:01:00  10.0        playing
1900-11-01 00:02:00  10.0        playing
1900-11-01 00:03:00  10.0        playing
1900-11-01 00:04:00  10.0        playing
1900-11-01 00:05:00  10.0  team_a_scores
1900-11-01 00:06:00  10.0        playing
1900-11-01 00:07:00  10.0        playing
```

---

**UPDATE**

Instead of `resample` you can use [`asfreq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.asfreq.html) which returns a plain DataFrame and behaves the way you expect it to

```
>>> data.asfreq('T').agg({'id': 'ffill', 'action': lambda _: 'playing'})
                       id   action
date                              
1900-11-01 00:00:00  10.0  playing
1900-11-01 00:01:00  10.0  playing
1900-11-01 00:02:00  10.0  playing
1900-11-01 00:03:00  10.0  playing
1900-11-01 00:04:00  10.0  playing
```

which would change the above solution to

```
df = data.asfreq('T')
df['id'] = df['id'].ffill()
df['action'] = df['action'].fillna('playing')
```

Comment: I understand your answer but I don´t understand why data.resample('T').ffill() works but when I use a different function to each column it doesn´t work (data.resample('T').agg('id': 'ffill', 'action': lambda x: 'sleeping'))